# Using a SRV DNS entry to connect to SQL Server in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, dns, srv

We have a cluster SQL Server and we use a SRV DNS entry to locate the service (i.e `sql.mycompany.com`).

```
MyCompany.com_tcp_http Service Location (SRV) [0][0][1433]sql.Mycompany.com
```

Now, how I can use the .NET SQLConnection to use this dns name (instead of the server name/IP)? Any ideas? 
Should I use `System.Net.Dns` to translate it first?

Comment: You might try this at serverfault.com

Comment: Does using sql.mycompany.com for Server not work?

Answer (score -1):

A .NET SQLConnection will not look up SRV records, only A records.

So yes, you will need to query your SRV record using System.Net.Dns yourself, parse and use the result in your connection string.